# Parsing a string with spaces

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I have lines in a file and each fieled in the line is seperated by spaces. Here's a simpliefied example of a line:

`208 "Person" "Anne Myers" "unsigned long" "hello" -1 false false false`

Within a single field, some words are seperated by spaces. i.e. "Anne Myers". This is a problem for parsing.

Any suggestions? Output should be the 9 fields for further processing.
Replacing the spaces within the field with some character is not feasible in my case.

Edit: all lines follow the same field order.

Comment: Do all the lines follow the same field order and type? If so, you may use regular expressions.

Comment: @Sergey go away regex

Comment: What should be output in this case.

Comment: Just use a parser generator and if that's overkill. Just write a parser!

Comment: Give me a char add it to my field if it's a quote I don't care what's there until I encounter another quote and if it's a backslash just add the next char to my field but apart from that, I don't really care about what it is. Now if I encounter a space. My field is ready to ship. So let's do so and start another field. Repeat!

Comment: I've made some changes to the post. Could you give some code for the regex please?

Comment: No just kidding. Your data looks very csvish so just use any csv parsing library out there and tell it what you want.

Comment: @kami no you'll not use a regex!

Comment: @kami Split the line according to spaces as usual. Next, loop through the resulting fields and check if adjacent ones need to be merged/concatenated by checking for starting and ending quotes.

Comment: Can be inside the string an escaped quote [e.q. \"]?

Answer (score 0):

One possible starting point would be a type that overloads `operator>>` to correctly read data in this format:

```
class field { 
    std::string content;
public:
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, field &f) { 
        char ch;

        // skip whitespace, then read one character
        is >> ch;

        // If it's a quote, read to the next quote
        if (ch == '"')
            std::getline(is, f.content, '"');
        else {
            // otherwise put it back, and read until white-space:
            is.unget();
            std::getline(is, f.content);
        }
        return is;
    }

    // While we're at it, I'm going to define output so we can see what was 
    // read in a single field easily:
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, field const &f) { 
        return os << "[" << f.content << "]";
    }
};
```

Then we can define a record type for a single line, that uses this type for the appropriate fields:

```
struct foo { 
    int a;
    field b;
    field c;
    field d;
    field e;
    int f;
    bool g, h, i;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, foo &f) { 
        return is >> std::boolalpha 
                  >> f.a 
                  >> f.b 
                  >> f.c 
                  >> f.d 
                  >> f.e 
                  >> f.f 
                  >> f.g 
                  >> f.h 
                  >> f.i;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, foo &f) { 
        return os << std::boolalpha 
                  << f.a << " " 
                  << f.b 
                  << f.c 
                  << f.d 
                  << f.e << " " 
                  << f.f  << " "
                  << f.g << " " 
                  << f.h << " " 
                  << f.i;
    }
};
```

Then we can test reading and writing a record:

```
int main() { 
    std::istringstream in
        { R"(208 "Person" "Anne Myers" "unsigned long" "hello" -1 false false false)" };

    foo f;

    in >> f;
    std::cout << f;
}
```

Result:

```
208 [Person][Anne Myers][unsigned long][hello] -1 false false false
```

This doesn't (currently) attempt to deal with a field that also includes a quote mark. That would be possible using either a C-like convention where we escape the quote mark with a back-slash, or a CSV-like convention where we include one quote mark by putting two quotes in a row in the input.

For example:

```
"Bill said: ""Go away""!"
```

...would be parsed as one field, containing the text:

```
Bill said: "Go away"!
```

Either is fairly easy to add, but you haven't said which (if either) you want to support, so I've left it out for now.